# How to get a syntax error resolved in SQLite in Android Studio?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

Here is the error I am getting in my code

```
::01-16 13:28:23.029    2782-
2782/com.example.innovative.firstapp E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "add": syntax error
01-16 13:28:23.049    2782-2782/com.example.innovative.firstapp E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting lastName=chauhan phone=1224567890 add=chandigarh firstName=param email=er.param90@gmail.com password=12345
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "add": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Reg_User(lastName,phone,add,firstName,email,password) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1113)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:686)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1573)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1445)
            at com.example.innovative.firstapp.dbHelper.insert(dbHelper.java:57)
            at com.example.innovative.firstapp.registrationForm.onClick(registrationForm.java:83)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4432)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18338)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-16 13:28:23.119    2782-2782/com.example.innovative.firstapp I/brcm-gr﹕ [gralloc_lock]: new usage 0x933
```

Here is my code snippet of registrationForm.java file

```
public class registrationForm extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    EditText e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7;
    Button b1, b2;
    public static final Pattern EMAIL = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9+._%-+]{1,100}" + "@" + "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,10}" + "(" + "."
            + "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,20}" + ")+");
    public static final Pattern FirstNAME = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10}");
    public static final Pattern LastNAME = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10}");
    public static final Pattern PASSWORD = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{4,16}");
    public static final Pattern PHONE = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{10}");
    public static final Pattern ADD = Pattern.compile("[A-Z a-z 0-9]{1,50}");
     dbHelper db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration_form);
        e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        e3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        e4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        e5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        e6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        e7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        db=new dbHelper(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String firstName = e1.getText().toString();
        String lastName = e2.getText().toString();
        String password = e3.getText().toString();
        String confirm = e4.getText().toString();
        String email = e5.getText().toString();
        String phone = e6.getText().toString();
        String add = e7.getText().toString();


        if (v == b1) {

            if (firstName.equals("") || lastName.equals("") || password.equals("") || confirm.equals("")
                    || email.equals("") || phone.equals("") || add.equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Field must not be null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if (!CheckFirst_name(firstName)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "ENTER VALID FIRST NAME", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (!CheckLast_name(lastName)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "ENTER VALID LAST NAME", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (!CheckPassword(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "ENTER VALID PASSWORD", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (!CheckEmail(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "ENTER VALID EMAIL ID", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (!CheckPhone(phone)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "ENTER VALID PHONE NUMBER", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (!CheckAddress(add)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "ENTER VALID ADDRESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (!confirm.equals(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Password doesn't Match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                    db.insert(firstName, lastName, password,email,phone,add);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        if (v == b2) {
            Intent i1 = new Intent(this, Login.class);
            startActivity(i1);
        }
    }

    private boolean CheckEmail(String email) {

        return EMAIL.matcher(email).matches();
    }

    private boolean CheckPassword(String password) {

        return PASSWORD.matcher(password).matches();
    }

    private boolean CheckFirst_name(String firstName) {

        return FirstNAME.matcher(firstName).matches();
    }

    private boolean CheckLast_name(String lastName) {
        return LastNAME.matcher(lastName).matches();
    }

    private boolean CheckPhone(String phone) {
        return PHONE.matcher(phone).matches();
    }

    private boolean CheckAddress(String add) {
        return ADD.matcher(add).matches();
    }

}
```

And here is the dbHelper class file code::

```
public class dbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static SQLiteDatabase db;

    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "User.db";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String KEY_ID="ID";
    public static final String KEY_fname="firstName";
    public static final String KEY_lname="lastName";
    public static final String KEY_pass="password";
    public static final String KEY_email="email";
    public static final String KEY_phone="phone";
    public static final String KEY_add="add";
    public static final String Table_User="Reg_User";

    public dbHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db)
    {
        _db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE"+ Table_User+ "("+ KEY_ID+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+
                KEY_fname+" text,"+KEY_lname +" text,"+KEY_pass+" text,"+ KEY_email+" text,"+ KEY_phone+" text,"+KEY_add+"text)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int _oldVersion, int _newVersion)
    {

           _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +Table_User);

        onCreate(_db);
    }


    public void insert(String firstName, String lastName, String password, String email, String phone, String add)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_fname, firstName);
        values.put(KEY_lname, lastName);
        values.put(KEY_pass,password);
        values.put(KEY_email,email);
        values.put(KEY_phone,phone);
        values.put(KEY_add, add);
       db.insert(Table_User, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
    public static String getSingleEntry(String email)
    {
        Cursor cursor=db.query("Reg_User", null, " KEY_email=?", new String[]{email}, null, null, null, null);
        if(cursor.getCount()<1)
        {
            cursor.close();
            return "NOT EXIST";
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("KEY_pwd"));
        cursor.close();
        return password;
    }



}
```

I am not able to figure out where is the problem in this code.

Comment: `...KEY_add+" text)");`.

Comment: @Luksprog is there any problem in this code?

Comment: You are missing a space between `KEY_add` and the rest of the sql declaration meaning you end up with `addtext`. After you change this line reinstall the app or change the version number of the database so the database it's reconstructed.

Comment: How to change the version number of database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure but I think it doesn't work, because 'add' is an SQL statement on itself.
(http://www.1keydata.com/sql/alter-table-add-column.html).

You can see in your code snippets that 'add' gets a highlighting every time

Comment: i have replaced it but there is no result

Comment: What do you mean with 'there is no result'. Does you still get an error or is the row not inserted in you db?

Comment: Now it says ::       1) table Reg_User has no column named lastName
01-16 14:09:43.850  11138-11138/com.example.innovative.firstapp E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting lastName=jeet phone=1234567890 firstName=param address=chd email=er.param90@gmail.com password=12345
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Reg_User has no column named lastName (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Reg_User(lastName,phone,firstName,address,email,password) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)

Comment: Did you edit the table structure after it was first created? Cause most of the times that doesn't work. You might want to delete your database (if thats possible because you lose the data in it) and run the app again so the database is newly created

Comment: yes , but now how can i can delete my database? i don't know. let me know how to do it.

Comment: You can delete the app on your device and reinstall it or use the same SQL query than in your onUpgrade method: `_db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +Table_User);`

Comment: You can also remove a database with `Context#removeDatabase(String database)`. For example in your starting `Activity`, but be sure to remove it afterwards or your database gets deleted every time your app starts

Comment: after deleting my app and reinstalling it i am getting this -->         **near "TABLEReg_User": syntax error
01-16 14:30:56.869  17351-17351/com.example.innovative.firstapp D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
01-16 14:30:56.869  17351-17351/com.example.innovative.firstapp W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e04930)
01-16 14:30:56.899  17351-17351/com.example.innovative.firstapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEReg_User": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEReg_User**

Comment: Where to put that code **Context#removeDatabase(String database)** ??

Comment: If you deleted the app, it's not needed anymore. The exception your now facing is because you are missing a space between CREATE TABLE and Reg_User. You have 'CREATE TABLEReg_User' while it should be 'CREATE TABLE Reg_User'

Comment: Thank u so much for your help :) it really worked and now there is no error or exception left : ) ) Now can you please tell me how to see the database?

Comment: Consider upvoting or mark it as an answer if it helped you. I'm afraid you can't see your database. At least not from within your app. There might be an app on the Play store to view an SQLite database, but your database consists outside of that app, so it won't be visible for that app. You just have to trust its there

Comment: Now i want to get a single entry from my database. i have put the code for it that too to make me enable for login with that entry. please check if is it correct?

Comment: Seems correct. You can always check the android developer page about databases (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). It also contains a paragraph about sqlite3 which is a tool in the android SDK to browse database contents. I've never used it, so if you're interested I advice checking the link

Comment: Actually i didn't get anything from that site that why i am asking. I am posting my login page code snippet below please check it out why it is not working .

Comment: I advice you to ask a new question with the problem you are now facing as this is going to be off-topic for this question

Answer (score 1):

You should not use "add" for KEY_add, because it is a reserved keyword for SQL.

Comment: I have replaced it but nothing happened.

Comment: The error is :: 1) table Reg_User has no column named lastName
01-16 14:09:43.850  11138-11138/com.example.innovative.firstapp E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting lastName=jeet phone=1234567890 firstName=param address=chd email=er.param90@gmail.com password=12345
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Reg_User has no column named lastName (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Reg_User(lastName,phone,firstName,address,email,password) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html), `ADD` is a reserved keyword.

You could quote it *everwhere* it is used (`"ADD"`), but this would be cumbersome.
Better use some other name for this column.

Comment: After using other variable error has been changed. now it says                1) table Reg_User has no column named lastName
01-16 14:09:43.850  11138-11138/com.example.innovative.firstapp E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting lastName=jeet phone=1234567890 firstName=param address=chd email=er.param90@gmail.com password=12345
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Reg_User has no column named lastName (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Reg_User(lastName,phone,firstName,address,email,password) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)